# Youtube API - Function to retrieve video image thumbnails fails when finding deleted video

Tags: jquery, dictionary, youtube-api, jsonp

I'm retrieving Youtube video thumbnails and such with a function that deals with comma-delimited string of video IDs :

```
function videoIDs(){
var videoArray = $("#comma-delimited-IDs").val().split(",");
var defArray = $.map(videoArray, function (videoIDs) {
var requestURLs = '//gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+ videoIDs +'?v=2&
format=5alt=json-in-script&callback=?';
return $.ajax({
type: "get",
dataType: "jsonp",
url: requestURLs,
success: function(data) {}
});
});
$.when.apply(null,defArray).done(function(){
$.each(arguments,function(i,arg){
var data = arg[0];
...
```

The map and done methods retrieve all videos first, in the chronological order they appear based on the comma-delimited string, before displaying them on the page. If this method wasn't used, Youtube would return a faster but random order of video thumbnails. The function above works for 2 video IDs or more, not for one single video ID. My current prob is when a video doesn't exist anymore on Youtube servers, the comma-delimited ID string containing the missing ID provokes a failure, thus making the function unable to retrieve any existing videos reflecting the IDs in the string. A work-araound to this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I would prefer being able to retrieve the thumbnails of the deleted videos (Youtube's default deleted video thumbnail) including those that are available in order to keep the total original video thumbnail count intact (based on ID string). Thx for sample/suggestion.

**UPDATE**:

It would appear that cross-domain issues hamper error handling of native ajax/jsonp processes, but luckily, jQuery-jsonp alleviates this with a 1kb plugin (see: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp ). The following amended code now looks like this:

```
function videoIDs(){
var videoArray = $("#comma-delimited-IDs").val().split(",");
var defArray = $.map(videoArray, function (videoIDs) {
var requestURLs = '//gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+ videoIDs +'?v=2&
format=5alt=json-in-script&callback=?';
return $.jsonp({  // replace $.ajax({ with $.jsonp({ 
type: "get",
dataType: "jsonp",
url: requestURLs,
success: function(data) {},
error: function(d,msg) {
alert("Error. Video ID non existant.");

// add function here to skip missing ID and proceed to next ID in CSV string

}
});
});
$.when.apply(null,defArray).done(function(){
$.each(arguments,function(i,arg){
var data = arg[0];

... // code that displays Youtube thumbnails etc of available IDs.
```

So now the alert pops up immediately when a video ID is non existant (deleted or private), but when that happens the function at its current state of code halts and does not retrieve any thumbnail image of videos whose existing IDs are found in the CSV string. Is there a way to iterate through all IDs found in the CSV string like in the following order? :

1. Request data of first ID in CSV string;
2. If alert (or not found), ignore and go to 2nd ID in CSV string, else, return data (thumbnail, etc) of first ID and then when completed, go to 2nd ID in CSV string;
3. Repeat above procedure in a chronological manner throughout all CSV string of IDs until done.

I'm kinda new to ajax-jsonp methods and my jQuery level is still beginners. I hope that someone can suggest a workable solution, thx for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! Some google searching gave me this kool sample of success/error handling supported by the jQuery-jsonp plugin (see above):

```
success: function(json, value) {
console.log(your-string-of-IDs);
},
error: function(xOptions, textStatus){
console.log(your-string-of-IDs);
}
```

Now it's only a question of replacing console.logs with the function(s) needed to filter, in my case, those missing thumbnail images. The error function effectively handles malformed video IDs and deleted/private video IDs. Using *new RegExp* and/or *replace* methods within a simple $.each loop will do the trick, heck, you could even replace the missing thumbnail with your custom image supplied by a one-frame video that you've uploaded to your Youtube channel. Hope this answer will help others. - Koolness